# Scaling a logo in bootstrap navbar on resizing browser or when the user browser zoom is not 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For the last 4 hours i am trying to get an image scaled when the browser resizes. The website uses bootstrap and the image is situated in the navbar-brand part. I know the navbar-brand part is normally used for a logo, but in this situation there is a bunch of text under the logo which is part of the image.

Now what i like to accomplish is to scale this image when the browser resizes. I have tried a bunch of different css option without any success.

My latest:

```
  .navbar-brand {
    max-height: 500px;
    } 
    .navbar-brand img
     {
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
         }
```

I could use some fresh input ?

Comment: Do you know the percentage of width your image will take?

Comment: @brian17han approx 31% i think.

Comment: did you try using media queries to check for screen width and apply the styles accordingly?

Comment: @Laiman good point. I did use the media queries for other elements but not for this element. Thing is, i would like it to scale smoothly, as you drag the browser window. And by using media queries it is not smooth (but i will try and see if this could be a backup plan)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments, the image will take certain percentage (31% in your case) of the `navbar` width. You can set `width` as percentage to `div.navbar-header` which is the wrapper of `img.navbar-brand`. Media query is added to make the added style compliance with Bootstrap navbar responsive rules.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
  .container>.navbar-header {
    width: 31%; /*31% as you mentioned in comments*/
  }
  img.navbar-brand {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg" class="navbar-brand">
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```